# Array not printed as expected

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner in Java and have been practicing different problems. 
The task is given a minimum and maximum, print an array of the odd numbers within the range. For example a minimum of 1 and maximum of 10 would print 3 5 7 9.

```
public class Practice {

static int[] oddNumbers(int minimum, int maximum) {

int[] arr = new int[10];

    for(int i = minimum; i <= maximum; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 != 0)
        {
            //System.out.println("Odd " + i);
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int min = 3;
    int max = 9;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oddNumbers(min, max)));
} 
}
```

My current output is "[I@15db9742". Is that the reference to the array? Would it also be better to use an ArrayList? Thanks!

UPDATE: I added Arrays.toString to my output. However my output is now giving me [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9] instead of simply 3 5 7 9 so it looks like its saving the last value multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Arrays.toString(..)` method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oddNumbers(min, max)));
```